# How do i split a list and and turn it into two dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, sublist

I have a list: `lst = [1,2,3,4,'-',5,6,7,'-',8,9,10]`
that needs to be split when the '-' character is encountered. and turned into a two dimensional list like so:
`[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]`
I have this so far and all it does is take the '-' character out:

```
l=[]
for item in lst:
   if item != '-':
      l.append(item)

return l
```

I'm learning how to code so I would appreciate the help

Comment: Why do you expect it to create a list of lists when all you do is append the item to a new list unless it's a `'-'`?

Comment: Why did you put a minus sign? Quote --- "that needs to be split when the '-' character is encountered. and turned into a two dimensional list like so: [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]"

Comment: @inquirer it's for an assignment and that's what the given list had

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I was saying that i don't understand how to do this and the code I included was all i was able to come up with which i know doesn't accomplish what i need

Comment: @abeishere can you show what you expect?

Comment: @inquirer the output:
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a new list that will contain only the numeric values:

```
new_list = [] #final result
l=[] #current nested list to add
for item in lst:
    if item != '-':
        l.append(item) # not a '-', so add to current nested list
    else: #if item is not not '-', then must be '-'
        new_list.append(l) # nested list is complete, add to new_list
        l = [] # reset nested list
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import more_itertools as mit

lst = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, '-', 5, 6, 7, '-', 8, 9, 10])
aaa = list(mit.split_at(lst, pred=lambda x: set(x) & {'-'}))
bbb = [list(map(int, i)) for i in aaa]
```

Output bbb

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```